# TypeScript typing: assigning an argument-less function to a function parameter which has arguments

Tags: typescript

I came across unexpected behaviour in TypeScript, and would like to understand the typing system better through this example.

Illustrating the example, we define a `main` function with a parameter which takes in a function with two arguments. We pass in a function which takes in *no* arguments as the default.

```
function noop(): void {
  console.log("I still work!");
}

function main(cb: (a: number, b: string) => void = noop) {
  cb(0, "0");
}

main();
```

Console:

```
I still work!
```

My expectation is that the linter would complain that `noop` takes in no arguments. So why does this behaviour still work?

(I was originally using `export default (...args any[]): any => {}` as my noop function from [therealemjy/noop-ts](https://github.com/therealemjy/noop-ts/blob/master/src/index.ts), which adds to my confusion: if `...args` is needed in the package, why does my simpler argument-less noop achieve the same thing?!)

Comment: See [the FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) on why this happens

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I wasn't aware this FAQ existed -- this answers my question perfectly (and I'll have a read through the rest -- the type system is very interesting!).